# GNOME Materia Theme Help

Tags: gnome3, theme, gtk3

I've been using Manjaro for a few months and it's been great so far. I'm using GNOME and the Materia GTK theme for my desktop.

However, while the Materia Light Theme works perfectly, I can't switch to the Materia Dark Theme for some reason. This is what happens when I try to change the theme:

[image]

System Info: Gnome 3.36.6, X11 display manager and 64-bit architecture

Is there some terminal command I can use to switch the theme? What should I do? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your answer to your question by entering it in the answer field, then accept it by clicking the checkmark outline next to the answer to indicate the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** GNOME automatically toggles between light and dark theme depending on the time of day (morning=light theme, night=dark theme). For anyone who encounters the issue, go to GNOME Extensions and search for "Night Shell Switcher" and "Night Theme Switcher". Turn both of these off.